# Add animate effects or classes when arriving in div on Vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm working on a project in Vue and need that when the user scrolls the page and arrive at a specified div, an effect or a class is added in that div, similar to [ScrollReveal](https://scrollrevealjs.org/)

Has anyone ever had to do something similar in Vue?

Here's the css code I own and I need it to run upon arriving in div

The title effect on h2 must be executed when it is displayed on the screen.

```css
@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

h1 {
  animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;
}

h2 {
  animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;
}
```

```html
<h1>
Hello World!
</h1>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<h2>
World Hello!
</h2>
```

Comment: I would just use [`vue-scroll-reveal`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-scroll-reveal). If you really had to implement it yourself, you could use the  [`IntersectionObserver` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), or track the scroll position of the target element.

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve the scroll to reveal effect by adding the the class `slide` having your css animation property set, when the user scrolls to its position. Below is a working example:

```js
new Vue({
  data: {
    el: document.getElementById('target-element')
  },
  methods: {
    isScrolledIntoView(el) {
      var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
      var elemTop = rect.top;
      var elemBottom = rect.bottom;
      isVisible = elemTop < window.innerHeight && elemBottom >= 0;
      return isVisible;
    },
    handleScroll() {
      /* if scrolled into view */
      if(this.isScrolledIntoView(this.el))
        this.el.classList.add('slide');
    }
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },
});
```

```css
@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.slide {
  animation: slideInFromLeft 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<h1 class="slide">
Hello World!
</h1>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<h2 id="target-element">
World Hello!
</h2>
```

Comment: You may accept this answer as the correct one if it helped you :)